# convert a Collection of Set<Integer> to a list of lists

Tags: java, list, collections, set, java-stream

I have a `HashMap<Integer, Set<Integer>>.`

I want to convert the `Collection` of set in the map to a list of list.

For example:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;
public class Example {

         public static void main( String[] args ) {
             Map<Integer,Set<Integer>> map = new HashMap<>();
             Set<Integer> set1 = Stream.of(1,2,3).collect(Collectors.toSet());
             Set<Integer> set2 = Stream.of(1,2).collect(Collectors.toSet());
             map.put(1,set1);
             map.put(2,set2);

             //I tried to get the collection as a first step
             Collection<Set<Integer>> collectionOfSets = map.values();

             // I neeed  List<List<Integer>> list = ...... 

             //so the list should contains[[1,2,3],[1,2]]
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
 map.values()
    .stream()
    .map(ArrayList::new)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your start was good: going for `map.values()` to begin with. Now, if you stream that, each element in the Stream is going to be a `Collection<Integer>` (each separate value that is); and you want to transform that each value to a `List`. In this case I have provided an `ArrayList` which has a constructor that accepts a `Collection`, thus the `ArrayList::new` method reference usage. And finally all those each individual values (once transformed to a `List`) are collected to a new `List` via `Collectors.toList()`

Answer (score 4):

A way without streams:

```
List<List<Integer>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(map.size());
map.values().forEach(set -> listOfLists.add(new ArrayList<>(set)));
```

Answer (score 3):

`map` from `Set<String>` to `ArrayList<String>` then `collect` to a list:

```
List<List<Integer>> result = map.values() // Collection<Set<String>>
                                .stream() // Stream<Set<String>>
                                .map(ArrayList::new) // Stream<ArrayList<String>>
                                .collect(toList()); // List<List<String>>
```